# How to find element whose class doesn't contain substring

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I intend to find an element in a page whose class doesn't contain a specific name. I must use DOM locator and "getElementsByClassName". For example I have the following list:

```html
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="one">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="two">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="three">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="four">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" name="five">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="six">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" name="seven">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="eight">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="nine">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="ten">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" name="eleven">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="twelve">12</li>
</ol>
```

I want to find the elements that do not contain "ui-selected".  This can be easily done with CSS's "not" and\or other methods, but here I must use DOM.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [:not CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```js
// Check your browser's console output for result
console.log(
    document.querySelectorAll('#selectable :not(.ui-selected)')
);
```

```html
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="one">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="two">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="three">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="four">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" name="five">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="six">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" name="seven">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="eight">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="nine">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="ten">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" name="eleven">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" name="twelve">12</li>
</ol>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/az2o5ens/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this works very well, but due to a didactic constraint I am not allowed to use querySelector and querySelectorAll. This is why I supposed that getElementsByClassName could be invoked with a not. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1980253 you can't do it with `document.getElementsByClassName`, but you could do it another way, for example — [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/yn2ej61n/).

Comment: @user1980253 did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modern browsers (Capable of HTML5), use the following code:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('selectable').querySelectorAll("li:not(.ui-selected)");
```

Otherwise, use the following code:

```
var ol = document.getElementById('selectable').childern, unselectedElements=[];
for (var j=0;j<ol.length;j++){
    if (!ol[j].getAttribute('class') || 
        !ol[j].getAttribute('class').match(/^ui\-selected/ig))
        unselectedElements.push(ol[j]);
}
```